# Openni node can't find device in simulation

Tags: ros, openni, pr2-tabletop-manipulation-apps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone:

I try to start the manipulation pipeline following [this](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/Tutorials/Starting%20the%20Manipulation%20Pipeline)

First launch pr2_gazebo pr2_table_object.launch

Since I want to use kinect sensor, I launch the pipeline like this:

```
roslaunch pr2_tabletop_manipulation_launch pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch stereo:=false
```

Everything looks good...but at last, it keeps telling me that:

```
[INFO] [1358084747.016012678, 248.407000000]: [/openni_node1] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

I trace the launch file and finally find that the pipeline will start the openni-related node from openni_camera_deprecated, which is now replaced by openni_launch.

How could I modify the launch file to make kinect sensor work?

I'm using ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks for any advice~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52100/openni-node-can%27t-find-device-in-simulation/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2013-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you're setting ROBOT=sim as in the tutorial.  It looks like it's trying to connect to the real hardware not the simulated kinect.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0